# Load image on ImageView from Gallery (Image is from my Google Photos)

Tags: android

I am getting pictures from the Gallery to my application. It works fine for photos located in my device (tablet, phone). It doesn't work when photos are from "the cloud", I mean, my Google Photos/Picasa.

Here is what I am doing:

```
    fotoPaciente.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // To open up a gallery browser
              Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent();
              photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
              photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
              //photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
              photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",
              Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

              photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
              startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Selecione uma imagem"),1);

            }


    });
```

Here is my activity result:

```
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                  if (requestCode == 1) {

                          // currImageURI is the global variable I'm using to hold the content:// URI of the image
                          currImageURI = data.getData();
                          fotoPaciente.setImageURI(currImageURI);
                          String pathFoto = currImageURI.getPath();

                        if (pathFoto.startsWith("/external")) {
                            pathFoto = getFilePathFromUri(currImageURI);
                        }



                  }
          }
  }
```

As I said, it works fine for pictures located in my device.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Picasa API [Here](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html)